# My suffix is an insect being, My whole is a human being

Tags: riddle, rhyme, affix-riddle

> My prefix does not have an end
>
> My suffix is an insect being.
>
> My infix wants to be your friend.
>
> My whole is a human being.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I think the word is

> '**INFANT**'

---

My prefix does not have an end

> 'INF' is [an abbreviation of infinity](https://www.abbreviations.com/abbreviation/Infinite) which is endless

My suffix is an insect being.

> 'ANT'

My infix wants to be your friend.

> 'FAN'

My whole is a human being.

> An 'INFANT' is a young human